# How to refresh page with javascript for N number of times through user input?

Tags: javascript

i have coded a script that should refresh the page for Number of times the user input the value .
here is the code

```js
var timeinmilliseconds = 60000;
var reloadCnt = window.sessionStorage.getItem("reloadCounter") ? parseInt(window.sessionStorage.getItem("reloadCounter")) + 1 : 1;

window.sessionStorage.setItem("reloadCounter", reloadCnt);
console.log(reloadCnt);
if (reloadCnt <= var x = document.getElementById('a').value;)
  setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(true) }, timeinmilliseconds);
```

```html
<form action="index.php" method="GET">
  <p>Your link: <input type="text" rows="5" style="width:200px; height:50px;"  name="link" /></p>
  <p>number of times: <input type="text" id="a"  name="times" /></p>

  <p><input type="submit"  rows="5" style="width:200px; height:50px;" / ></p>
</form>
```

what am i doing wrong in this code?everything is working correctly but its doesnt refresh the page.
plus if i set the code to

```
if ( reloadCnt <= 3 )
```

it works.and if i set it to

```
    if ( reloadCnt <= var x = document.getElementById('a').value; )
```

it doesnt works.
please help

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: i tried posting the code but its not getting in proper format.thats why i uploaded it on pastebin and provided a link to the code

Comment: `document.getElementById('a').value` returns a string value. Did you handle it?

Comment: @31piy no.i am total noob to javascript

Comment: Try changing it to `parseInt(document.getElementById('a').value))`

Comment: You never read out the input value for the link? Does it have a purpose, or you just want to refresh the current page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Matt Morgan that your attempt to assign a variable inside a conditional:

```
if ( reloadCnt <= var x = document.getElementById('a').value; )
```

probably means you need to brush up on your understanding before proceeding.

But here is a working demo for you.  (Not having your index.php, which I assume populates the textbox "a", I've done it client-side and fetched the posted value from the querystring.  Once you've got it working, you can always revert to `document.getElementById('a').value`)

You'll also want to clear your sessionStorage variable when the user next hits the page, otherwise when you try to test it twice in a row, reloadCounter will still be where it was at the end of the last run.

```
<form  method="GET">
 <p>Your link: <input type="text" rows="5" style="width:200px; height:50px;"  name="link" /></p>
 <p>number of times: <input type="text" id="a"  name="times" /></p>

 <p><input type="submit"  rows="5" style="width:200px; height:50px;" / ></p>
</form>
<script>   

function getParameterByName(name) {
    var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);
    return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
    var timeinmilliseconds = 600;
    var reloadCnt = window.sessionStorage.getItem( "reloadCounter") ? parseInt(window.sessionStorage.getItem( "reloadCounter")) + 1 : 1;
    var times = getParameterByName('times');
    if (times)
    {
        window.sessionStorage.setItem( "reloadCounter", reloadCnt );
        console.log(reloadCnt + ' / ' + times);
        if ( reloadCnt <  times )
            setTimeout(function(){ window.location.reload(true) }, timeinmilliseconds);
    }
    else
    {
        window.sessionStorage.setItem( "reloadCounter", 0 );
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can u try using this instead.

```
if (reloadCnt <= document.getElementById('a').value;)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a some fundamental problems with your JavaScript.  It's important that you understand *why* this is not working if you want to be able to use JS well in the future.

This statement is not doing what you intend:

```
if ( reloadCnt <= var x = document.getElementById('a').value; )
```

You are saying "if reloadCnt is less than or equal to some thing" where "some thing" is the result of the statement:

```
var x = document.getElementById('a').value;
```

This statement is *assigning* `document.getElementById('a').value` to the variable x.  The return value of such an assignment is always `undefined` in JavaScript.  This means what you've effectively written is the same as:

```
if ( reloadCnt <= undefined )
```

This is always going to be false, which is why it's not working for you.

There are two other issues:

1. Your jQuery lookup will return a string, which you should convert to a number before comparing it to another number.
2. You don't need a semicolon inside your conditional.

In the end, this is probably what you want to write:

```
if (reloadCnt <= Number(document.getElementById('a').value)) { ... }
```